# Why onDestroyed() not called after app pushed out from memory?

Tags: android, performance

1) Activity is on `onStop()` state. 
 Example: overview button tapped.

2) Working with phone till android pushed out app from memory.
  Example: gaming

3) Overview tapped and app tapped then crash

Any solution to destroy it when pushed out from memory?

Answer (score 0):

There is no assurance that onDestroy will ever be called.  Do not depend on it, it should be used for opportunistic cleanup only.  Especially in the case of a crash, it will NOT be called, because the app may not be in a state where its safe to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a couple things. Manage your absolute necessary clean up in the Application file. (low memory) callback can call the same method.

One idea would be to have a baseclass or abstract model where you keep a reference to the the active version in Application class. Then if low memory is called, you can manually call your (selectedActivity.OnDestroy).

It's a work around to make sure that a low memory calls your cleanup. You can also add one for unhandledException listener to make sure a crash can call your cleanup as well. Depends on how important your final cleanup is in the event of app closure.

If the cleanup is too heavy or time intensive, you can simply set a "bad closure" flag in a DB or shared pref that you check on startup and do your cleanup on the next app launch.